# When something gives you a needed boost and subsequently recharges you

Tags: word-request, verbs, idioms, sentence-structure

Please imagine following your work-out and when you feel depleted, you need a very nutritious food like a protein shake. You have it and after drinking your shake, you feel too better in comparison with several minutes ago and you feel you've got the lost energy.

Or

imagine you are really tired and someone gives you a massage and you enjoy a lot and feel energetic and then want to indicate your feelings.

Or

imagine in summertime you have exercised / worked etc. a lot and feel tired and someone gives you a cold beverage and you want to thank them.

---

Why I brought up them all in one single question?

Because in our language we have a multilateral, informal idiom which can be used in all of the situations I painted above.
Which one of the following idioms work in all of my scenarios in AmE:

> That massage really / Drinking that protein shake / That cold beverage really:
>
> **a)** livened me up
>
> **b)** gave me a needed boost
>
> **c)** recharged me
>
> **d)** brought me back to life

Comment: There are simply too many possibilities. All your suggestions (and dozens more) are perfectly valid. You can Google synonyms for *revive, perk up, restore, energise,* etc., but to a first approximation one choice is as good as another, so there's no scope for a single "correct" answer here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not looking for many choices. I need to clarify if my sentences work? Then if they are natural and finally which one sounds more natural in the cases I described. If no one, then what expression would be the first thing that comes to one's mind reading my context.

Comment: As I said, all your suggestions "work". But it's just Off Topic proofreading if that's all you're asking, and it's POB if you're actually asking for one or more alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest [Rejuvenate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rejuvenate).

```
      That ....... rejuvenated me.
```

Also Resuscitate/Resuscitant.

According to M W:
: to bring (someone who is unconscious, not breathing, or close to death) back to a conscious or active state again

```
    That drink was a resuscitant.
```

I can't cite many links as I wanted to, so kindly look for further information.

Answer (score 0):

For  catch all word you can use "invigorated" meaning to energise or to give strength.

```
That ... really invigorated me".
```

The four phrases in the question are all fine and would be understood although c is not common. Massage may not be ideal with a or d